# Validators are not clearing in reactive forms in angular8?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `form` in my `component` in which i have some fields which display on certain conditions. Like if i select an `option1` in `UI` so some fields will display and if will select `option2` on `UI` so some other fields will display. So as i have conditional fields which i have to display so i also have conditional `form` fields `validators`. So here are my some functions which i call to set validations on options select. There are 3 options on UI i.e: Company, Broker, Individual. user can select any of these option and validators will be set based on select of this option.

```
  setCompanyTypeValidators(){
    this.firstFormGroup.get('companyName').setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.firstFormGroup.get('nTn').setValidators(Validators.required);
  }
  setBrokerTypeValidators(){
    this.firstFormGroup.get('companyName').clearValidators();
    this.firstFormGroup.get('brokerName').setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.firstFormGroup.get('nTn').setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.firstFormGroup.get('cnic').setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.firstFormGroup.get('refrences1').setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.firstFormGroup.get('refrences2').setValidators(Validators.required);
  } 

 setIndividualTypeValidators(){
    this.firstFormGroup.get('name').setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.firstFormGroup.get('cnic').setValidators(Validators.required);
 }
```

By default on page load in `ngOnInit` i call `setCompanyTypeValidators()` to set `company` type `validators` and when user `switch` to another option let say on `Broker` type so this `function` is called

```
setradio(e: string): void {
 this.selectedLink = e;
 if (this.selectedLink === 'company') {
   this.firstFormGroup.clearValidators();
   this.firstFormGroup.markAsUntouched();
   this.firstFormGroup.get('nTn').markAsUntouched();
   this.firstFormGroup.reset();
   this.firstFormGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
   this.setCompanyTypeValidators();
 } else if(this.selectedLink === 'broker'){
   this.firstFormGroup.clearValidators();
   this.firstFormGroup.markAsUntouched();
   this.firstFormGroup.reset();
   this.firstFormGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
   this.setBrokerTypeValidators();
 }else if(this.selectedLink === 'individual'){
   this.firstFormGroup.clearValidators();
   this.firstFormGroup.markAsUntouched();
   this.firstFormGroup.reset();
   this.firstFormGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
   this.setIndividualTypeValidators();
 }
}
```

`Form` is defined as

```
  this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    phone: ['', Validators.required],
    otpcode: [''],
    companyName: [''],
    nTn: [''],
    brokerName: [''],
    refrences1: [''],
    refrences2: [''],
    refrences: [''],
    name: [''],
    cnic: [''],
    companynamepartnership: [''],
    partnershipcnic: [''],
    companynameproprietyship: [''],
    proprietyshipntn: [''],
    userTypeId: [3],
    insertedBy: [''],
    companyType: [''],
  });
```

Now problem is that if i switch to option `Broker` so broker validators are set using `setradio` function
and after filling all the fields of `form` , `form` still is `invalid`. When i logs all `form` `fields` `errors` so it logs to `console` using this `function`

```
logg(){
   let fields = ['phone','otpcode','companyName','nTn','brokerName','refrences1','refrences2','refrences','name','cnic','companynamepartnership','partnershipcnic','companynameproprietyship','proprietyshipntn','userTypeId','insertedBy','companyType']
 fields.forEach(item => {
  console.log(this.firstFormGroup.get(item).errors,this.firstFormGroup.valid, item);
  })
}
```

I don't know why is it happening?

[image]

Comment: check the value you received to setRadio function. BTW, I suggest instead of clear/setValidators, you enable/disable the forms controls - a control.disabled is not checked by Angular-

Comment: check value of what?

Comment: I think that the problem must be in your function setRadio. write 'console.log(e)` to see the value of "e"

Comment: @Eliseo i implemented the enable/disable approach which you mentioned in your comment and that worked for me :)